# u-boot stuck at Starting Kernel

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, embedded, boot-loader, u-boot

**My Target Setup:**

```
SOC: STM32H743 (Cortex m7 single core)
Internal Flash: 2MB
Board: Waveshare CoreH7XXI
On-board DRAM: 8MB, Start_Address: 0xd0000000, Size_in_bytes: 0x7A1200
SDCARD: 1GB

Bootloader: mainline u-boot (only I've modified the device tree and added my board files, almost everything is default)
kernel:     mainline linux (compiled with stm32_defconfig configuration + some tweaks in menuconfig)
```

**My Host (PC) Setup:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 20 LTS on windows10 WSL2
Text Editor: VSCode (Visual Studio Code)
Debug Probe: STLink V2
Debug Software: Openocd + gdb-multiarch integrated in VSCode
```

---

**Raw U-boot serial console:**

```
U-Boot 2020.07-00610-g610e1487c8-dirty (Sep 07 2020 - 22:06:45 +0430)

Model: Waveshare STM32H743i-Coreh7 board
DRAM:  7.6 MiB
MMC:   STM32 SD/MMC: 0
In:    serial@40004400
Out:   serial@40004400
Err:   serial@40004400
Hit SPACE in 3 seconds to stop autoboot.
stm32_sdmmc2_send_cmd: cmd 6 failed, retrying ...
stm32_sdmmc2_send_cmd: cmd 6 failed, retrying ...
stm32_sdmmc2_send_cmd: cmd 6 failed, retrying ...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
U-Boot > fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} zImage
1403424 bytes read in 326 ms (4.1 MiB/s)
U-Boot > fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} stm32h743i-coreh7.dtb
15116 bytes read in 14 ms (1 MiB/s)
U-Boot > setenv bootargs console=ttySTM1,115200n8
U-Boot > bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
Kernel image @ 0xd0008000 [ 0x000000 - 0x156a20 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at d0408000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0xd0408000
   Loading Device Tree to d064f000, end d0655b0b ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Even I made a uImage with the below command but again it didn't boot.

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0xd0008000 -e 0xd0008000 -n "Linux kernel" -d arch/arm/boot/zImage uImage
```

**u-boot log:**

```
U-Boot > bootm ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at d0008000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux kernel
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1403424 Bytes = 1.3 MiB
   Load Address: d0008000
   Entry Point:  d0008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at d0408000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0xd0408000
   Loading Kernel Image
```

**U-boot Env:**

```
U-Boot > printenv
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=coreh7
board_name=coreh7
boot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}
boot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}
boot_prefixes=/ /boot/
boot_script_dhcp=boot.scr.uimg
boot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scr
boot_syslinux_conf=extlinux/extlinux.conf
boot_targets=mmc0 
bootcmd=run distro_bootcmd
bootcmd_mmc0=devnum=0; run mmc_boot
bootdelay=3
bootfstype=fat
cpu=armv7m
distro_bootcmd=for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; done
fdt_addr_r=0xD0408000
fdtcontroladdr=d06572a0
fdtfile=stm32h743i-coreh7.dtb
kernel_addr_r=0xD0008000
loadaddr=0xD0400000
mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then devtype=mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
pxefile_addr_r=0xD0428000
ramdisk_addr_r=0xD0438000
scan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done;
scan_dev_for_boot_part=part list ${devtype} ${devnum} -bootable devplist; env exists devplist || setenv devplist 1; for distro_bootpart in ${devplist}; do if fstype ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} bootfstype; then run scan_dev_for_boot; fi; done; setenv devplist
scan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; then echo Found ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi
scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; done
scriptaddr=0xD0418000
soc=stm32h7
stderr=serial@40004400
stdin=serial@40004400
stdout=serial@40004400
vendor=waveshare

Environment size: 1873/8188 bytes
```

you can download my kernel .config file from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCqxrus25ichPoyE6uJOdGJCOD6sA?e=2wzFLx) (default config: stm32_defconfig).

you can download my u-boot .config file from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCqxrus25ichPouBAPFSV8equ62UA?e=7KuwoK).

you can download my modified device tree from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCqxrus25ichPovTT1fZuXeX8E9xQ?e=I4CVxR).

you can download my u-boot specific modified device tree from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCqxrus25ichPowHbt0CsqMaRST3g?e=pv1hrz).

Comment: Please include what `printenv` shows for the environment. A full serial console log is also better than snippets, thanks.

Comment: Dear @TomRini I've edited my post and added the environment vars and raw serial console log. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @TomRini Also I have GDB + openocd integrated in vscode. I can put beakpoints in u-boot source code but I'm newbie in u-boot and I'm not familiair with u-boot infrastructure. I can put breakpoints wherever you suggest and then I share the results here if it's useful.

Comment: Try `console=ttySTM1,9600n8` (replace `9600` with whatever baud rate you want to use); you can't use `console=${console}` because there is no `console` u-boot environment variable defined; also with the uImage, you can't use load and entry addresses of `0x80008000` - there is no memory there - try using `0xd0008000` for both (although the `bootz` should work)

Comment: Also, if you defined `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK` when you built your kernel, try adding `earlyprintk` to your `bootargs` ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen thank you so much for helping. I changed both of addresses to 0xd0008000 and console to ttySTM1,115200n8. but again it's not booting. I've also modified my question and added these changes to it. I have another question too. why should I use ttySTM1 ? what is ttySTM1 ? I thought I should use tty1 like my pc.

Comment: Try `ttySTM0` then - I guess the first usart in the device tree is not enabled ... `ttySTM` is the name the `stm32` serial driver registers with (at least since [this](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/857601/) patch in 2017)

Comment: @MurrayJensen Awesome news: It worked with ttySTM0 !  thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing any `bootargs` to the kernel, and since you're bypassing the logic to have a regular Linux distribution provide that for you, you need to pass in something that says where the console is, to Linux, so it will print out messages, as well as your root device.

Comment: Now I've added this boot arg :  setenv bootargs console=${console} but again, it stuck at "starting kernel". Thanks for guiding me.